# Cant get the column name that is updated in a historical table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, triggers

I have a table in sql server with a lot of columns that can be updated every time. Now i want a trigger that inserts into a historical table that i have created the values that are updated in the main table. The historical table is like this:VarName(to store the name of the column that was updated in the main table, ID(the id of the row in the main table), OldValue(the old value that was updated, NewValue(the new value), Date(date updated). Im using this code but I want the trigger to automatically detect the columns changed and storing their names in VarName column. keeping in mind that in one row in the main table can be updated more than one field so if 3 field are updated, the historical table will add 3 rows with the occurring updates with their respective column name in the main table and their old and new values.
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].UpdateOnMainTable
   ON  [dbo].[MainTable]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

```
    INSERT [dbo].[Historical] (VarName, ID, OldValue, NewValue, Date)
        SELECT ===> the code here
        FROM inserted i
        INNER JOIN deleted d
            ON i.ID = d.ID
```

END
GO
I want a code that fills my historical table as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

First, your structure requires that the data types be compatible for the columns in your history table.

Second, you need to unpivot and then work from there:

```
with ic as (
      select i.id, v.*
      from inserted i cross apply
           (values ('col1', i.col1), ('col2', i.col2), ('col3', i.col3)
           ) v(col, val)
     ),
     dc as (
      select d.id, v.*
      from deleted d cross apply
           (values ('col1', d.col1), ('col2', idcol2), ('col3', d.col3)
           ) v(col, val)
     )
insert into historical (varname, id, oldvalue, newvalue, date)
    select ic.col, ic.id, dc.val, ic.val, getdate
    from ic join
         dc
         on ic.id = dc.id and
            ic.col = dc.col and
            (ic.val <> dc.val or
             ic.val is null and dc.val is not null or
             ic.val is not null and dc.val is null
            );
```

Note that if the columns have different types, then you need to cast them (presumably to strings) in the `values()` statements.

Comment: @RediPrifti . . . The same place you would put the `insert`, presumably in an `update` trigger.

Comment: yes I did that but I try to update only one value it affects 9 rows 
I used the code that is given above.

Comment: @RediPrifti . . . I fixed the code a few minutes ago.  I had missed the `join` condition on the column name.

Comment: Yeah i was looking fr another join there but u added it first. Thanx man u helped me a lot :)